# Alias Git push command with custom script

Tags: git, config, alias

I'm looking to alias the actual `git push` command in Git to run things like unit tests before committing to GitHub.

Here's my `config` file in `.git/`

```
[alias]
  push = !echo "custom push"
  kk = !echo "hi" # => this works...
```

It seems to ignore the push. Is this possible? If this is not possible, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can't alias a push due to conflict with push command, but you could try using "pre-push" hook, see the following [patch](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/8/19/2996404) for more details.

Another approach would be to use [post-receive](http://help.github.com/post-receive-hooks/) hook on GitHub where you would configure it to do a POST to your integration server which will run unit tests, etc and approve or reject the changes. Depending on your set up, that might not be practical, however.

Comment: Hmm.. this is really hard to follow - is this patching the actual git library? I think that's a bit overkill..

Comment: Yes, it's not very straightforward. Maybe creating a 'xpush' alias is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this to combat the obnoxiousness of `git push` printing out what I wanted to run but doesn't run it! Yes it has reasons (you should not push every piece of garbage to remote) but my remotes are my GitHub fork and I can suffer any garbage pushed there.

This is based on [Eugene Kay's `.bashrc`](https://github.com/EugeneKay/scripts/blob/master/HOMEDIR/.bashrc#L144-L202) (I kept the `cd` from there but removed the `which git` part which didn't work for me). Add it to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` to taste:

```bash
function git() {
  # Path to the `git` binary
  GIT="/usr/bin/git"

  # Sanity check
  if [ ! -f ${GIT} ]
  then
    echo "Error: git binary not found" >&2
    return 255
  fi

  # Command to be executed
  command=$1

  # Remove command from $@ array
  shift 1

  # Check command against list of supported commands
  case $command in
  "cd")
    cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/${1}
    ;;
  "push")
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
      $GIT push || $GIT push -u origin $($GIT rev-parse --abbrev-ref @)
    else
      $GIT ${command} "$@"
    fi
    ;;
  *)
    # Execute the git binary
    $GIT ${command} "$@"
    ;;
  esac

  # Return something
  return $?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an alias, I would use git's pre-commit hook.

http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'd prefer to have as little overhead in commits as possible. Running unit tests each time is a pain. This should only run when I push to an external "production" branch. Also, Github doesn't offer pre-receive hooks, so hitting it on the other side wouldn't work either.

Comment: You can skip the `pre-commit` hook on any given commit with `-n` or `--no-verify`.  Of course that also skips the `commit-msg` hook, which you may or may not want to do, and if you get in the habit of always using `-n` you may forget to leave *out* the `-n` on the one you wanted checked. :-)  There's no perfect solution here; you just have to pick which drawbacks you can live with.